# When $\mathbb {P} (X \ge Y)\ge \frac{1}{2}$, $\mathbb {P} (Y \ge Z)\ge \frac{1}{2}$ $\Rightarrow $ $\mathbb {P} (X \ge Z)\ge \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, statistics, order-theory

Let $X, Y, Z$ be random variables. When does the following hold?

$$\mathbb {P} (X \ge Y)\ge  \frac{1}{2} \text{ and } \mathbb {P} (Y \ge Z)\ge  \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \mathbb {P} (X \ge Z)\ge  \frac{1}{2}.$$

Could you specify some necessary or sufficient conditions under which the above holds when $X, Y, Z$ are independent?

**Updates 1:**

Considering the counterexample in the answer given by @RyszardSzwarc, I updated my findings as follows:

A- When $X, Y, Z$ are independent and have **symmetric** continuous distributions **with unique medians**, the above holds (still not sure about that this holds when $X, Y, Z$ are dependent).

B- When the distributions of $X, Y, Z$ do not have unique medians, even if they are symmetric, the above may not hold.

**Specific questions:**

1- If $X, Y, Z$ are independent and have distributions **with unique medians**, does the above hold? This can be written as follows:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F_Y(x)dF_X(x) \ge  \frac{1}{2}, \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F_Z(y)dF_Y(y) \ge  \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F_Z(x)dF_X(x) \ge  \frac{1}{2}.$$

Please provide a proof or counterexample.

2- What happens if the analysis of the above question is restricted to the class of distributions whose **cdfs are continuous and strictly monotone** over their supports (implying that the median is unique)? For a subclass of this class including those distributions with densities, the claim is equivalent to the following

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F_Y(x)F'_X(x)dx \ge  \frac{1}{2}, \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F_Z(y)F'_Y(y)dy \ge  \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F_Z(x)F'_X(x)dx \ge  \frac{1}{2}.$$

Here, $F_X, F_Y, F_Z$ denote the cdfs of $X, Y, Z$, respectively. $X, Y, Z$ have unique medians when $F_X(m_X)=F_X(m_Y)=F_X(m_Z)=0.5$ have unique solutions $m_X, m_Y, m_Z$.

**Updates 2:**

Based on the counterexample provided by @stochasticboy321, I realized that **the set of independent RVs with symmetric continuous distributions whose medians are unique** is the only set of independent RVs over which the proposed probabilistic order is transitive. Note that based on the counterexample provided by @RyszardSzwarc we can design symmetric continuous distributions with non-unique medians for which the implication does not hold (the continuous version of $Y$ has a symmetric bimodal continuous distribution   with multiple medians).

$\color{red}{\text{Prove, refine, or provide a counterexample:}}$ I **guess** this can be generalized to the set of **all RVs with symmetric distributions whose medians are unique** (including constants and symmetric distributions with unique medians) as

> The union of the set of real numbers and the set of RVs with symmetric continuous distributions whose medians are unique is the **largest** set of RVs over which the proposed probabilistic order is transitive.

Here,  $(X,Y, Z)$ is called to have a symmetric distribution if for some $m_1, m_2, m_3$:

$$(X-m_1,Y-m_2, Z-m_3) \sim - (X-m_1,Y-m_2, Z-m_3).$$

**Updates 3:**

By the Bonferroni's inequality and

$$\mathbb {P} (X \ge Z)\ge \mathbb {P} (X \ge Y , Y \ge Z)$$

we have

$$\mathbb {P} (X \ge Y)\ge  p, \mathbb {P} (Y \ge Z)\ge  q \Rightarrow \mathbb {P} (X \ge Z)\ge  p+q-1.$$

Hence, to have a probabilistic order over **the set of all RVs**, $p=q=1$ seems to be the only choice for which $p=q=p+q-1$.

Comment: Observation. By substituting $X'=X-Z$ and $Y'=Y-Z$ the problem reduces to $P(X'\ge Y')\ge {1\over 2},$ $P(Y'\ge 0)\ge {1\over 2}$ imply $ P(X'\ge 0)\ge {1\over 2}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thank you! Nice simplification, but it makes $X'$ and $Y'$ dependent. So it can be used for the general case when the three random variables can be dependent.

Comment: [Here is a counterexample where X,Y,Z are independent dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260072/what-is-the-most-unfair-set-of-three-nontransitive-dice). Otherwise, your question is too broad.

Comment: @MikeEarnest thank you! I tried to narrow the question.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X=-1,\, Z=0$
$$P(Y=1)=P(Y=-1)={1\over 2}$$ The variables $X,\,Y,\,Z$ are  independent and
$$P(X\ge Y)=P(Y={-1}) ={1\over 2}$$

Comment: Thank you @RyszardSzwarc! Based on this, can we design a counterexample in which $X, Y, Z$ have independent continuous distributions?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to approximate the distributions of $X$,$Y$ and $Z$ by continuous distributions with densities, whose mass is mostly concentrated at $-1$ for $X,$ at $\pm 1$ for $Y$ ( we can assume that this density is symmetric) and finally at $0$ for $Z.$

Comment: I just updated the question based on your feedbacks.

Answer (score 3):

Continuity requirements in such questions are mostly not effective in avoiding discrete counterexamples, because one can always smear out discrete laws by adding a skinny continuous noise. Implementing this essentially needs a "robust" counterexample to start with, i.e., one where the hypotheses are met with some wiggle room, and the conclusion is still violated. I execute this idea below (Pretty sure that the construction can be simplified, this is just what I started with).

---

Let $X,Y,Z$ be independent with the discrete laws $$ X = \begin{cases} -1 & \textrm{w.p. } (1-0.1)/2\\ 1 & \textrm{w.p. } (1-0.1)/2\\ 100 & \textrm{w.p. } 0.1\end{cases}\\ Y = \begin{cases} 0 & \textrm{w.p. } (1-0.1)/2\\ 1/2 & \textrm{w.p. } (1-0.1)/2\\ 50 & \textrm{w.p. } 0.1\end{cases}\\ Z \sim \mathrm{Unif}\{-1/2,2\} $$ The important point here is that the supports of $X,Y,Z$ are completely disjoint.

Then we have $$ P(X \ge Y) = (1+0.1)/2 = \frac12 + 0.05\\ P(Y \ge Z) = \frac{1+0.1}{2} = \frac12 + 0.05 \\ P(X \ge Z) = \frac{1 -0.1}{4} + 0.1 < \frac12 - 0.1.$$ The important point here is that $X\ge Y$ and $Y \ge Z$ with probability strictly larger than $\frac12.$

Now, we need to deal with the unique medians and continuity requirements. This can be handled essentially by relying on a convergence in distribution idea (I'll leave it to you to actually prove the following).

> Lemma:  Let $X$ be a discrete random variable, and $N$ be a standard Gaussian independent of $X$. Then for any $\sigma > 0, X + \sigma N$ has a continuous law, and for any finite collection of open intervals $I_1, \cdots, I_k,$ it holds that $$ \lim_{\sigma \to 0} \max_{i \le k} | P(X+ \sigma N \in I_i) - P(X \in I_i)| = 0.$$

In effect, by adding $\sigma N$ to $X$ with tiny $\sigma,$ we're taking the point masses in the law of $X$, and smearing them out in such a way that almost all of the mass ends up around the points of $X$, but all continuity properties are satisfied.

But note that you can write the events $X \ge Y, Y \ge Z, X \ge Z$ as unions of intervals. $$\{X \ge Y\} = \{X \in (0.99, 1.01)\} \cup \{X \in (99.9,100.1)\} \\ \{Y \ge Z\} = \{Z \in (-0.51, -0.49)\} \cup \{ Y \in (49,51)\}, \\ \{X \ge Z\} = \{X \in (99,101)\} \cup (\{X \in (0.99, 1.01)\} \cap \{Z \in (-0.51,-0.49)\}).$$

This means that for there exists some small enough $\sigma,$ such that it holds that $$ P(X + \sigma N_1 \ge Y + \sigma N_2) \ge P(X \ge Y) - 0.001\\ P(Y + \sigma N_2 \ge Z + \sigma N_3) \ge P(Y \ge Z) - 0.001\\ P(X + \sigma N_1 \ge Z + \sigma N_3) \le P(X \ge Z) + 0.001,$$ and we conclude that $(X+ \sigma N_1, Y + \sigma N_2, Z + \sigma N_3)$ serve as a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Could you let me know in the counterexample whether the three distributions have unique medians?

Comment: @Amir They meet your stronger strictly monotone cdf condition, so yes. You should try to prove this.

Comment: Thank you! Could you confirm that it generally holds only for symmetric distributions with unique medians (when they are independent)?

Comment: When independent this is trivial, you don't need any notion of $Y$ at all: argue that if $X \equiv -X, Z \equiv -Z$ and they are independent, then the joint law $(X,Z) \equiv (-X,-Z)$. But then $P(X \ge Z) = P(-X \ge -Z) = P(X \le Z).$ But $1 = P(X \ge Z) + P(X < Z) \le P(X \ge Z) + P(X \le Z) = 2P(X \ge Z)$.

Comment: Thank you, but I here consider the general symmetry: there exists $m$ such that $X-m\sim -(X-m)$. You may check my 2nd and 3rd updates.